# How to get current url using Selenium Perl API

Tags: perl, url, selenium

I am just trying to get the current absolute url of the page. Here is the snippet of the code

```
my $url_str = "BEFORE";
$sel->storeLocation("url_str");
$sel->comment(URL is $url);

Send command: storeLocation|url_str|
Got result  : OK
Comment     : URL is BEFORE
```

It does not seem to work. I tried with $url_str, \$url_str as arguments to the storeLocation but in vain. Please help on what exactly am I missing here

Comment: sorry to bother you guys .. $sel->get_location() is the API that works

Comment: Either post that as an answer and accept it, or delete the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Perl API uses the more Perlish 'get_' as a prefix instead of the Selenium standard of 'store'.  Also the Perl API uses underscores instead of camel case.

```
# returns the current url
$sel->get_location()
```

Also see:

- The [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) docs on CPAN
- The [Test::WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25/lib/Test/WWW/Selenium.pm) docs on CPAN
- [The official Selenium docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html)